# Hooking up async method to event handler with ASMX

Tags: asmx

I have a standard asmx webmethod, that when referenced creates the following method in the client proxy:

```
msr.SendAndReceiveAsync("Hello");
```

This is just an example, any method you generate with asmx automatically gets the Async method included.

I can call this method fine, what I can't seem to get right is hook up the event handler.

Best examples I can find recommend this:

```
msr.SendAndReceiveCompleted += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(msr_complete);  

        }

        private void msr_complete(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

This does not compile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the compilation error? Also, I believe you know that WCF should be used for all new development, but I'm adding that here for those who don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web reference should have generated a completed event handler similar to this for you to use:

```
msr.SendAndReceiveCompleted += new SendAndReceiveCompletedEventHandler(msr_complete);
```